# aframe text causing weird looks

Tags: html, text, desktop-application, aframe

A-Frame Version: 0.8.0

Platform / Device: Desktops

I have an a-entity text inside an a-box element and the text looks blurred out. The a-box is slightly translucent and seems to be disfiguring the text.

These are the lines the box is in

```
<a-box id="box1" material="src: img/info.svg; transparent:true;" position="0 2 -1.8" rotation="0 0 0" depth="0" width="1" height="1" scale="0.001 0.001 0">
    <a-entity id="info" width="1" position="0 0 0.6" text="value: This is the Mac desktop computer IXD has purchased to supply their students with adequate equipment so that they are capable of accomplishing projects even if they do not have their own Mac OS based system; color:#000;">
    </a-entity>
    <a-circle id="box1-close" radius="0.06" class="clickable" material="src: img/close.svg; transparent:true;" remove-yellow position="0.4 0.4 0.6" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 0">
    </a-circle>
</a-box>
```

I suspect the problem may be with the anti aliasing but I have already manually turned it on in my a-scene. On closer inspection it may have something to do with the border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you mean about a possible antialiasing problem. I don't know exactly why this is happening, but I've had similar problems trying to render white text on a black background before. In this case it seems to have something to do with putting the text inside of the `a-box` element. The following code block will fix the issue:

```
<a-box id="box1" material="color:black; transparent:true; opacity: 1" position="0 2 -1.8" rotation="0 0 0" depth="10" width="1" height="1" scale="1 1 0.05">
  <a-circle id="box1-close" radius="0.06" class="clickable" material="src: img/close.svg; transparent:true;" remove-yellow position="0.4 0.4 0.6" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 0">
  </a-circle>
</a-box>
<a-entity id="info" width="1" position="0 2 -1.55" text="value: This is the Mac desktop computer IXD has purchased to supply their students with adequate equipment so that they are capable of accomplishing projects even if they do not have their own Mac OS based system; color:white;">
</a-entity>
```

Placing the text outside of the `a-box` removes the text blur.

Answer (score 0):

For the box, maybe try setting the z scale to be slightly larger than 0.

A quick test:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-text-box

```
  <a-box id="box1" material="transparent:true;" position="0 2 -1.8" rotation="0 0 0" depth="0" width="1" height="1" scale="1 1 .1">
    <a-entity id="info" width="1" position="0 0 .5" text="value: This is the Mac desktop computer IXD has purchased to supply their students with adequate equipment so that they are capable of accomplishing projects even if they do not have their own Mac OS based system; color:#000;">
    </a-entity>
    <a-circle id="box1-close" radius="0.06" class="clickable" material="src: img/close.svg; transparent:true;" remove-yellow position="0.4 0.4 0.6" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 0">
    </a-circle>
  </a-box>
```